# Why lambda function keeps the form of the last step of loop?

Tags: python, string, loops, lambda

I was trying to create a list of lambda functions for a list of strings.

```
columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']
formats = []
for i, v in enumerate(columns)
    formats.append(lambda x: str(i + 1) + '%4f' %x)
```

and the output of `formats[0](12)` was supposed to be `1:12.0000`

but the result turns out that no mater I use `formats[0](13)`, `formats[1](26)` or `formats[2](12)`, the output is always like `3:##.####`.

It seems that it always keep the format of the last loop. Why? Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://www.toptal.com/python/top-10-mistakes-that-python-programmers-make error #6. Python binds variables in closures when function is called, not when it is defined.

Comment: Thanks! exactly the same problem. Really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the value of `i` isn't bound to the lambda at creation time. One way to get around this is to pass it in as a default argument

```
formats.append(lambda x, i=i: str(i + 1) + '%4f' %x)
```